# Label Rotation in GeoServer SLD based on CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, sld

I'm styling a series of vector data in Polar Stereographic Projection (specifically EPSG 3031) using GeoServer and SLDs.  These maps can be rotated E/W, so if the labels are fixed they appear upside-down in places. (Example here: [SCAR ADD](https://www.add.scar.org/) (hold shift and drag to rotate)).

Is there a function that I could apply to the Rotation feature in SLDs to calculate the rotation of the labels based on the CRS rotation/meridian of the map?

Comment: You could go for one or more custom SLD that you send with the GetMap request to the service as SLD=, or SLD_BODY=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rotation is being handled by the client so the server has no idea of the rotation angle.

For example - https://www.add.scar.org/ogc/60/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=add%3Aantarctic_facilities&STYLES=add%3Aantarctic_comnap_facilities_2018&CRS=EPSG%3A3031&SRS=EPSG%3A3031&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=-1057600%2C-699200%2C-699200%2C-340800

is a tile after I have applied rotation to the map.

Your only hope it to modify the client to pass a [rotation environment parameter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html) into the server and use that in the label SLD:

```
<ogc:Function name="env">
   <ogc:Literal>rotation</ogc:Literal>
   <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
```

Comment: That's really helpful - thanks!  I wondered if there was something like that I could use in the server and SLD.  I'll look into it.